# What Metrics Are Used in the Output of Gensim's evaluate_word_pairs?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, similarity

Gensim offers evaluate_word_pairs function for [evaluating semantic similarity](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_4.0.0/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#evaluating).

Here is an example from its page:

```
model.wv.evaluate_word_pairs(datapath('wordsim353.tsv'))

Out:
((0.1014236962315867, 0.44065378924434523), SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.07441989763914543, pvalue=0.5719973648460552), 83.0028328611898)
```

I would like to know what metrics are used to generate each value(0.1014236962315867, 0.44065378924434523,...) in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation for `evaluate_word_pairs()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.evaluate_word_pairs):

> **Returns**
>
> - **pearson** *(tuple of (float, float))* – Pearson correlation coefficient with 2-tailed p-value.
> - **spearman** *(tuple of (float, float))* – Spearman rank-order correlation coefficient between the similarities from the dataset and the similarities produced by the model itself, with 2-tailed p-value.
> - **oov_ratio** *(float)* – The ratio of pairs with unknown words.

Per your output, it looks like the Pearson result is still just a plain tuple, while the Spearman result has been reported as a named tuple. But in each case, it appears the correlation-coefficient is 1st, then the p-value.

Note that the `oov_ratio` is reported as the *percentage* of test words that weren't known to the model.

Consult other references for definitions/explanations of the [Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) and [Spearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) coefficients/p-values.